# Ionic Tabs hide on keyboard not working

Tags: android, ios, tabs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic project, I'm using the following tabs:

```
<ion-tabs  class="tabs-icon-top tabs-background-dark tabs-color-light hide-on-keyboard-open">


<!-- MAP Tab -->
<ion-tab ng-hide = "true" title="Map" icon="icon ion-map" href="#/tab/map">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-map"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- CHAT Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Chat" icon="icon ion-chatbubble" href="#/tab/chat">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chat"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab></ion-tabs>
```

However, when opening the keyboard, on both iOS and Android, the tabs remain, even if I have the keyboard plugin installed.

When I try to hide any other object using "hide-on-keyboard-open", it works smoothly.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: `hide-on-keyboard-open` is just adding `display: none`, so try opening up either Safari or Chrome inspector and see why that style isn't being applied

Comment: how would I trigger the keyboard open event? Would this be the same as focusing in the input?

Comment: Ah I guess I assumed you had access to a testing device or simulator, if you can find one you can use Safari or Chrome to inspect the app while it's running on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in ionic source that's causing this not to work, there's an open issue on github, check the repo and chime in there but it's not working on android 4.4.4 device.